# How to show this iff relationship?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $M$ be a linear operator in $L(V)$, where $V$ is a vector space. How to show

$\ker(M^k) = \ker(M^{k+1})$ iff $R(M^k) \cap \ker(M) = \{0\}$.

---

It is not difficult to show $\ker(M^k) \subset \ker(M^{k+1})$, but I have no idea about how to show that.

Comment: Consider elements. For the => direction, assume that the r.h.s is wrong and show that then the l.h.s must be wrong. If the r.h.s is wrong, there is a $0 \neq x \in R(M^k) \cap Ker(M)$. Use this $x$ to find a $y \in Ker(M^{k + 1}) \setminus Ker(M^k)$. Similarly, for the <= direction, assume that the l.h.s is wrong and show that then the r.h.s must be wrong. If the l.h.s is wrong, there must be a $0 \neq u \in Ker(M^{k + 1}) \setminus Ker(M^k)$ (according to your inclusion $Ker(M^k) \subseteq Ker(M^{k + 1})$). Use this $u$ to find a $0 \neq v \in R(M^k) \cap Ker(M)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\mathrm{ker}(M^k)=\mathrm{ker}(M^{k+1}).$ Let $v\in \mathrm{ker}(M).$ We have to show that $v=0$ or $v\notin \mathrm{range}(M^k).$ Well, if $v\in \mathrm{range}(M^k)$ there exists $w$ such that $v=M^kw.$ Since $v\in \mathrm{ker}(M)$ it is $0=Mv=M^{k+1}w,$ from where $w\in \mathrm{ker}(M^{k+1})=\mathrm{ker}(M^k).$ But, then $v=M^kw=0.$

Conversely, assume $\mathrm{range}(M^k)\cap \mathrm{ker}(M)=\{0\}.$ As you have said it is$\mathrm{ker}(M^k)\subset \mathrm{ker}(M^{k+1}).$ So we need to show $\mathrm{ker}(M^{k+1})\subset \mathrm{ker}(M^k).$ Let  $v\in \mathrm{ker}(M^{k+1}).$ Then $0=M^{k+1}v=M(M^kv).$ That is, $M^kv\in \mathrm{range}(M^k)\cap \mathrm{ker}(M)=\{0\},$ from where $v\in \mathrm{ker}(M^k),$ and we are done.